# Give a bijection between unitary, degree one representations of Z and elements of T.

Tags: representation-theory

Definition: My book defines $\mathbb{T}$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $\mathbb{T}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}$

I'm trying to answer this question: "Give a bijection between unitary, degree one representations of $\mathbb{Z}$ and elements of $\mathbb{T}$." and I'm having some trouble developing an intuition about it. My book tells me that a one dimensional unitary representation is a homomorphism, $\phi :G \to \mathbb{T}$(where $G$ is any group).

However, I don't really see any particular reason why there would be a bijection between the set of unitary 1 dimensional representations in $\mathbb{Z}$, and the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. This is my first time posting here, so please let me know if I've violated any of the rules or if I should rephrase my question. Any help is appreciated.

Here's where I'm at with this problem: I know that a representation is a mapping from a group into the set of automorphisms of a vector space. Specifically here, the one dimensional unitary representations of $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of mappings where each mapping takes elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and assigns those elements to elements of the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{T}$. So, as I understand it, I need a mapping, which takes as parameters representations(which are also mappings) and assigns uniquely each representation to a complex number on the unit circle.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!  Your question is most welcome, and follows the [faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).  You might want to add some more details about what Z,G,T,C are.  If you mean the integers, you may want to use \mathbb{Z} in math mode (between dollar signs) to get $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: And what is a degree one representation? Note that, since $\Bbb Z$ is cyclic $=\langle 1\rangle$, any homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ is determined by its value at $1$.

Comment: A degree one representation produces complex numbers, right? 1x1 matrices with elements in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what direction to take the homomorphism thing. I see that the outputs you get in $\mathbb{C}$ correspond to multiples in  $\mathbb{Z}$ depending on the starting point.

Comment: I think I see it. Any unitary representation of degree one puts numbers in $\mathbb{C}^*$. But all of those mappings are uniquely determined by what they do to 1. There are $\mathbb{T}$ options to assign 1 to in any given mapping, and each destination for 1 defines a unique mapping. Therefore, there are $\mathbb{T}$ such representations.

Comment: @doliver It seems you have answered your own question. Please consider posting your comment as an answer, so that the question gets removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

A unitary map on $\mathbb C^1$ is of the form $z\mapsto az$ where $a\in\mathbb T$. Since $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, every unitary representation $\varphi$ of $\mathbb Z$ on $\mathbb C^1$ is determined by $\varphi(1)$; which according to the above is the multiplication by some $a\in\mathbb T$. This gives the bijective correspondence  $\varphi \mapsto a$.